# TypeScript `groupBy` typings

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to write a `groupBy` function, so far the type system is not so happy with my work.

```
export function group<
    T extends object,
    K extends (keyof T & string),
    R = T[K] extends string ? string : never
>(
    data: T[],
    groupBy: keyof T
): { [group: R]: T[] }
```

The first error that I got is that `R` in `{ [group: R]: T[] }` is not `string` or `number`.

The signature actually doesn't work at all for the data set of

```
group([{ name: 'Johnny Appleseed', age: 17 }], 'name') // R should be string
group([{ name: 'Johnny Appleseed', age: 17 }], 'age') // R should be never
```

However, both `R` is `never` while `K` is `"name" | "age"`

I have to manually narrow down type parameter with `group<{name: string, age: number}, 'name'>` to make `R` be `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index signature must be either `string` or `number`. No union types, no generic types nothing else will do except `string` or `number`.

We can still achieve the behavior you want if you use two function signatures, one that accepts only `string` keys and the other that only accepts `number` keys:

```
export declare function group<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends string>(data: T[], groupBy: K): { [group: number]: T[] }
export declare function group<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends string>(data: T[], groupBy: K): { [group: string]: T[] }


let groupByString = group([{ name: 'Johnny Appleseed', age: 17 }], 'name') 
let groupByNumber = group([{ name: 'Johnny Appleseed', age: 17 }], 'age')
```